# Redirect after authentication is to http when it should be https

Tags: azure, docker, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Starting point here is a standard template from Microsoft for ASP.NET Core: I used Visual Studio => New Project => `.NET Core` => ASP.NET Core Web Application

I then ticked the box for HTTPS support and configured `Work or School account` authentication against an existing Azure AD instance.

Then no matter whether I use `http` or `https` to run it locally, the redirect url during authentication always points to https - which is exactly as it should be.

When I deploy this into regular Azure App Service, it has the same behavior, which is fine.

**BUT:** If I create a docker image from this and deploy it to an Azure AppService with container support (linux-based in this case), then the authentication redirect always goes against http, which is really not what I want.

For reference, this is the Dockerfile used to build the image:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY HttpsTest/HttpsTest.csproj HttpsTest/

RUN dotnet restore HttpsTest/HttpsTest.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/HttpsTest
RUN dotnet build HttpsTest.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish HttpsTest.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HttpsTest.dll"]
```

Please note that I am not fiddling around with custom certificates inside the container, as I am using Azure App Service to terminate the SSL connection (and bring its own certificate with it along the way).

I am pretty sure there is something I am overlooking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1), the discussed configuration might help you solve the **HTTP** redirect issue.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that way. I got it working by setting the scheme manually:

`app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });`

Comment: Could you please explain the exact cause why it is working after adding the above line as mentioned by @Masterfu. That would be really helpful.