# Error AADSTS50011 when using Blazor and AAD in a Azure Container App

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-msal, azure-container-apps

I have a `.net8` containerized `Blazor Server` Web app running in an `Azure Container App`. The application is deployed from the image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.1-alpine3.18-amd64`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.1-alpine3.18-amd64 AS base

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh

COPY /src .
COPY /NuGet.config .
COPY /Directory.Build.props .

ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"

RUN dotnet publish "Portal/Portal.csproj" -r linux-x64 -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Portal.dll"]
```

A custom domain has been added so that I can access my app at the URL `https://admin-dev.mydomain.ca` which redirects the user to `https://admin-app-dev-01.xxx.canadacentral.azurecontainerapps.io`.

The UI requires user authentication through `Azure Active Directory`. I have a Registered App set up and the Redirect URL is something like `https://admin-dev.mydomain.ca/signin-oidc`.

[image: Registered App Redirect URL Configuration]]

I have found many questions on Stack Overflow regarding AADSTS50011 that deals with the TLS termination issue (i.e. the `https` gets lost in the load balancer). So in my app, I have added the following:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
        .Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>
        (
            options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
                                           ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
                // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
                // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit 
                // configuration.
                options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
                options.KnownProxies.Clear();
            }
        )
        ;

...
```

And later on:

```
...

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

//  This is required to manage the case of the Container App being contacted
//  over HTTP which causes a mismatch with the configured Redirect URL.
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

**Problem**

I thought I had everything properly configured but it is not the case. When I go to `https://admin-dev.mydomain.ca`, I am redirected to the AAD login page. I enter my credentials and then it fails when AAD tries to redirect me to `http://admin-dev.mydomain.ca` because the URL is not part of the authorized Redirect URL.

> AADSTS50011: The redirect URI
> 'http://admin-dev.mydomain.ca/signin-oidc' specified in the request
> does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application
> 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'. Make sure the redirect URI
> sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure
> portal.

I thought I had follow the documentation but I obviously missed something and I do not know what.

**Question**

How do I configure my containerized Blazor app running in a Container App to allow authentication through AAD?

Comment: Make sure you set FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED = true and ssl redirects url to True and check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576236/redirect-url-changes-from-https-to-http-after-users-authenticated-with-azure-act

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353601/redirect-after-authentication-is-to-http-when-it-should-be-https

Comment: @Rukmini Nice, you are exactly right :) Could you add it as a response to the question so that I can mark it as an accepted answer?

Comment: Sure I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error usually occurs if the Azure Ad redirect URL is not configured properly that is if the redirect URL is not matching the request redirect URL.

To resolve the error, you have to configure proxy servers and load balancers. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

- Set the environment variable **`ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED` to true.**
- Set ssl redirects url to true.

By default, TLS is enabled if the controller redirects HTTP clients to 443 port.

In ingress yaml file,

```yaml
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

If you are using .NET, then make sure to set headers as true.

**References:**

[Redirect URL changes from https to http after users authenticated with azure active directory in azure aks - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576236/redirect-url-changes-from-https-to-http-after-users-authenticated-with-azure-act) by Hoang Minh

[azure - Redirect after authentication is to http when it should be https - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353601/redirect-after-authentication-is-to-http-when-it-should-be-https) by Itay Podhajcer

Comment: Is the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` annotation required? If so, what is its role in all this?

Comment: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` can help to resolve the issue by allowing you to define more complex URL patterns that can be matched by the Ingress controller but may not be required in all the scenarios